# JSON to CSV in Python with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

My json file is something like this:

```
[{"traceId": "23245342fbvf3", "kind": "SERVER", "localEndpoint": {"serviceName": "client", "tags": {"host_ip": "10.42.0.180", "http.method": "POST"}, {"traceId": "veeg34vdfgd4", "duration": 1313178, "localEndpoint": {"serviceName": "product_service", "ipv4": "172.17.0.8"}}]
```

I use this script:

```
def parse_nested_json(json_d):
   result = {}
   for key in json_d.keys():
     if not isinstance(json_d[key], dict):
        result[key] = json_d[key]
     else:
        result.update(parse_nested_json(json_d[key]))
   return result

json_data = pd.read_json("data.json")
json_list = [j[1][0] for j in json_data.iterrows()]
parsed_list = [parse_nested_json(j) for j in json_list]
result = pd.DataFrame(parsed_list)
result.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False)
```

This works fine but only for the first part of the json file. Is it possible to get both parts in the csv indicating the headers like 0/traceId (for the first one) 1/traceId(for the second one)

Comment: Help us to help you .How exactly you want your csv to look like and how it is now

Comment: I get everything nicely from' traceId' to 'http.method' but nothing form the second column (after POST)

Comment: your json isn't valid

Comment: your sample JSON is not valid.  obvious answer with valid JSON is `pd.json_normalize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing up your sample JSON.  `pd.json_normalize()` extracts all the embedded `dict`.  Then you can do `to_csv()`

```
js = [{'traceId': '23245342fbvf3',
  'kind': 'SERVER',
  'localEndpoint': {'serviceName': 'client',
   'tags': {'host_ip': '10.42.0.180',
    'http.method': 'POST',
    'traceId': 'veeg34vdfgd4',
    'duration': 1313178,
    'localEndpoint': {'serviceName': 'product_service',
     'ipv4': '172.17.0.8'}}}}]

pd.json_normalize(js).T
```

|  | traceId | kind | localEndpoint.serviceName | localEndpoint.tags.host_ip | localEndpoint.tags.http.method | localEndpoint.tags.traceId | localEndpoint.tags.duration | localEndpoint.tags.localEndpoint.serviceName | localEndpoint.tags.localEndpoint.ipv4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23245342fbvf3 | SERVER | client | 10.42.0.180 | POST | veeg34vdfgd4 | 1313178 | product_service | 172.17.0.8 |